# Handling IAC bytes in TcpClient.Read()

Tags: c#, buffer, arrays, ascii, tcpclient

I am reading data from a Telnet server with TcpClient as a byte array and convert into string with ASCII encoder, i.e.:

```
int size;
byte[] buf;
tcpclient.Read(buf,0,MAX_BUFFER_SIZE);
string resp = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding().GetString(fullBuffer, 0, fullBuffer.Length);
```

and have `buf` with the read bytes. I want to extract (and answer later) IAC commands inside `buf`, not to have them in `resp`. Do you have an efficient suggested way.

What first comes to my mind is: Find "\0xFF" strings in `resp` (a) if followed by "\0xFF", replace "\0xFF\0xFF" with "\0xFF" (b) if not extract followed byte as IAC and answer. `resp.Remove()` two characters.

Is that an efficient solution? Do you suggest to solve it in `byte[]` level (is there a way to have some values in `byte[]` that are ignored by ASCII encoder?) or after encoding into `string`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What first comes to my mind is: Find "\0xFF" strings in resp (a) if followed by "\0xFF", replace "\0xFF\0xFF" with "\0xFF" (b) if not extract followed byte as IAC and answer. resp.Remove() two characters.

Part a will work, but part b is lacking. There are several commands that consist of more than 2 bytes. You're going to have to do more work and determine how many bytes each command should consume. For instance, the SB command will contain a variable number of bytes depending on what the suboption is.